# Mocking back-end function I don't have access to with Cypress

Tags: javascript, mocking, frontend, cypress

I am trying to develop a front-end app based on a back-end with a behavior driven approach with the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.
I found that in cypress you can mock a function by using stub(object, method).

(In my case I want to mock `axios.create` But when using `stub(axios, 'create')` I get the error:
`ReferenceError: axios is not defined.`)

My problem is that I don't have access to the object, since I am only developing the front-end.

So my question: How do I get access to axios, or any other back-end function?

Answer (score 0):

without having more context, this is the challenge i believe you're currently facing:

- `stub(axios, 'create')` is failing because the `axios` binding hasn't been initialized in the file where it's being referenced, which results in the `ReferenceError`

note that `axios` is not inherently a "back-end" function, it's an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) that provides an HTTP client to be used in either browser ("front-end") or node.js ("back-end") environments. it sounds like you're using it in a front-end context, which means you probably have it downloaded as a node package and intend to have it run within the browser.

my initial recommendation would be to import the `axios` package into the same test suite/context you're attempting to run `stub(axios, 'create')`, to ensure the binding is initialized before attempting to reference it.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that worked,
But fundamentally, If I wanted to use a function only defined in the back-end, is there a good way/best practice to mock that? (Again without having access to said back-end).
I would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.